# Node loop: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to implement a infinite loop, doing some work every 5 second inspired by [*a single threaded HTTP monitor*](http://letsnode.com/example-of-what-node-is-really-good-at).

```
function doWork(callback) {
    console.log("doWork called");
    //todo: do work
    callback();
}

function query_doWork() {
    doWork(function() {
        setTimeout(query_doWork(), 5000);
    });
}

query_doWork();
```

Instead of printing "*doWork called*" every 5 second, it just flush a lot of this, and exit in this state:

```
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

Maybe I don't something fundamental about Node.js, but I get why this is not working properly. What is the reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `setTimeout` you should define what is the function you want to call. What you are doing instead, is calling it. That's why you enter in an *infinite* recursion loop. So replace:

```
setTimeout(query_doWork(), 5000);
```

with:

```
setTimeout(query_doWork, 5000);
```